# How to print a line from a text file without a certain character

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

Not quite sure if this question is a duplicate, but it seems like it isn't, after searching for a fair while.

Let's say I have these lines of text in text file.

```
    Q5) What is 1+1
    A) = 1
    B) = *2
    C) = 0
    D) = -342
    E) = 121
```

The correct answer, `B) = *2`, is written with a `*` mark over the line. How would you print this line, but without the character, so the line would be printed like so:

```
    Q5) What is 1+1
    A) = 1
    B) = 2
    C) = 0
    D) = -342
    E) = 121
```

I am still new to Python, but I understand that:

```
print lines[3]
```

Would print the specific line. Yet I would like to know how to print a line, without a certain character.

Any help and explanation on the Coding, will be much appreciated. Thanks Guys.

Comment: Is the correct answer always marked with `*`? If yes, then is it possible that an answer contains `*`?

Comment: Strings in Python have a built in `replace()` method. Used this way: `'B) = *2'.replace('*', '')` should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks n9code, but no, any answers will not contain the character *.

Comment: Depending on how complex this is, look into `str.replace` or `re.sub`.

Comment: Please provide some more  input/output samples. It is hard to understand your question from just this one example.

Comment: If you put the `*` at the end (right side) instead then a slice would be easier.  You could test `line[-1] == '*'` and use `print lines[3][:-1]`

Comment: The * symbol indicates the Correct Answer, which will be presented on a text file, but when the program is run, then the * sign will not be present, +Lutz Horn

Comment: Why don't you just create a dictionary to map question numbers to the answer letters so that you can avoid asterisks all together?

Comment: Will the file contain multiple questions? If yes what is the format of the file? E.g. is the number of answers fixed?

Comment: @n9code Yes the number of questions is fixed, and the format is a txt file, and yes 5 answers per question, 10 questions.

Comment: @Ash by saying format I mean the formatting inside the file, e.g.: `1 line of question, 5 lines of answers, 1 empty line` and 10 times the same.

Comment: @n9code, this is the format, with each of the answers and questions taking up one line each. There is also a one line space between each question.
            Q5) What is 1+1
            A) = 1
            B) = 0
            C) = 2
            D) = -342
            E) = 121

Comment: @Ash updated my answer, so you can parse the whole file, and obtain a `list of Questions`

Comment: Again, just use a dictionary to map questions to answers. You can avoid complications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
Given this input:

```
Q1) What is 1*1?
   A) = 0
   B) = *1
   C) = 2
   D) = -1
Q2) What is 1-1?
   A) = *0
   B) = 1
   C) = 2
   D) = -1
Q3) What is 1/1?
   A) = 0
   B) = *1
   C) = 2
   D) = -1
Q4) What is 1%1?
   A) = *0
   B) = 1
   C) = 2
   D) = -1
Q5) What is 1+1?
   A) = 1
   B) = *2
   C) = 0
   D) = -342
   E) = 121
```

There are many ways to tackle this.  These are my first thoughts:

```
import re

def ask_user(answer):
    user_ans = raw_input("> ").strip()
    if user_ans == answer:
        print "Correct!\n"
        result = True
    else:
        print "Wrong!\n"
        result = False

    return result

question = None

with open('test.txt') as test:
    for line in test:
        if line[0] == 'Q':
            if question:
                ask_user(answer)
            question = line
        else:
            m = re.match(r'(.*?)\*(\d+)', line)
            if m:
                line, answer = m.groups()
                line = "%s%s\n" % (line,answer)

        print line,

# Final question
ask_user(answer)
```

Comment: There's no need to test the line for an asterisk where there is a replacement.

Comment: Thanks for the Comment, but I'm this code prints all the lines at once, rather than a few at a time. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @Ash: A *few* lines at a time?  How many, and what happens in-between?

Comment: For instance, the code that I use, prints lines like this  print lines[7]  
  print lines[8]
  print lines[9]
  print lines[10]
  print lines[11]
  print lines[12], which then will wait for further user input, then print the next lot agian.

Comment: When I run your code, it prints out all the lines in the Text File Immediately. Is their a way to solve this, or am I not understanding?

Comment: @Ash: of course we can solve it, I just need to understand it.  The file you show only has 6 lines in it, so where did lines 7 to 12 come from?  You say "the next lot", what constitutes a "lot", is there more than one question in the input file maybe? (you don't say that anywhere that I can see)

Comment: Ok sorry, the lines 7-12 were just an example. My code is written out like this. I first Print the first 6 lines, just like i wrote above. These 6 lines represent the Question, then 5 answers. Then, their is an If statement, where when the user finishes with the If statement, it goes to lines 7-12, (which is the second question).

Comment: Maybe I am not implementing your code correctly, but when I run your code, it prints the whole file completely, not the certain lines, such as 0-6 (for the first question) as I'd hoped it would.

Comment: @Ash: OK, but that is unrelated to your question!  The question is about replacing a single character, not pausing when you hit another question.  I could post code to do that, but it is a whole other ball-park.  Maybe you should post your code.

Comment: Thanks cdarke, I think I understand now what to do, I was just unsure of what the code did. Maybe i'll upload the code and a different question regarding the pausing later

Comment: @Ash:  solution posted, I hope it helps.  You'll notice I'm using a regular expression this time.

Answer (score 2):

A `*` might appear in:

- the question, e.g. `Q5) What is 2*2` seems a likely possibility,
- as a marker for the correct answer (as shown by OP),
- elsewhere within an answer (a reasonable assumption)

Blind use of `str.replace()` on every line of the file is not practical as it will affect all line types possibly corrupting questions and answers.

Maybe a further assumption can be that when `*` is used to mark the correct answer it will always appear at the same location, i.e. one space after the equals sign, so this might be a better solution:

```
line = line.replace(') = *', ') = ', 1)
```

which will replace the *first* occurrence of `) = *` with `) =`. It is unlikely that the same sequence of characters would appear elsewhere.

If the whitespace is variable, e.g. tabs mixed with spaces or different numbers of spaces, you can turn to a regular expression like this:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'([A-Z]\)\s+=\s+)\*(.*)$')
line = pattern.sub(r'\1\2', line)
```

Comment: This is a great catch, I forgot about the question having an asterisk. +1

Comment: The author stated that no `*` can be found in the answer body :)

Comment: @n9code: you're right, thanks, OP did state that in a comment which I only just read :). But this doesn't change the viability of this answer which isn't going to break if `*` ever does appear in an answer at some future time.

Answer (score 1):

You want to print lines without a certain character, right? Just iterate and replace:

```
for line in data:
    print line.replace('*', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

you could read the file in for loop itself as the other user has done .By using strip function you can remove the unwanted trialing and leading edges

**My code:**

```
a=open("filename","r")
contents=a.readlines()
i=0
for content in contents:

    print str.strip(content.replace("*",""))
    print i
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Thank you, but since this prints all lines in the text file, how would you only print certain lines, rather than all?

Comment: Yes exactly, print everything in the Line except the * sybmol

Comment: This does that only it prints all except the * character

Comment: Give it a run and see

Comment: Thanks, but the code still prints all the lines of my text file at once, rather than certain ones at a time. Its probably still my very basic understanding of python at the moment. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It is printing one line at a time you could see it after running this

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not have a `*` in your answer body, just do the following:

```
>>> questions = Question.from_file('your_file.here')
>>> print(questions[0])

Q5) What is 1+1
A) = 1
B) = 2
C) = 0
D) = -342
E) = 121

>>> print(questions[0].correct_answer)

B) = 2
```

Below you may find the definitions:

```
class Question(object):
    def __init__(self, body):
        super(Question, self).__init__()

        self.body = body
        self.answers = []
        self.correct_answer = None

    def add_answer(self, answer, is_correct=False):
        self.answers.append(answer):

        if is_correct:
           self.correct_answer = answer

    def __repr__(self):
        result = self.body + '\n'
        for answer in self.answers:
            result += answer + '\n'

        return result

    @classmethod
    def from_lines(cls, lines):
        question = cls(lines[0])

        for ans_line in lines[1:]:
            body = ans_line
            is_correct = False
            if Answer.CORRECT_MARK in ans_line:
                body = ans_line.replace(Answer.CORRECT_MARK, '')
                is_correct = False
            question.add_answer(Answer(body, question, is_correct))

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, filename):
        questions = []
        with open(filename) as q_file:
            lines = q_file.readlines()

            for i in range(0, len(lines), 6):
                questions.append(cls.from_lines(lines[i:i+6]))

class Answer(object):
    CORRECT_MARK = '*'

    def __init__(self, body, question, is_correct=False):
        super(Answer, self).__init__()

        self.body = body
        self.question = question

        question.add_answer(self, is_correct)

    def is_correct(self):
        return self.question.correct_answer == self

    def __repr__(self):
       return self.body
```